# choose which menu(s) appear in the "Parent item" select box in Drupal

Tags: drupal

When creating or editing node in Drupal, we have a field called "choose parent item".

In this one I just have one menu. I would like to control which menu to load in this selectbox?

I am using Drupal 6.

Comment: Which version of Drupal are you using? It makes a difference.

Answer (score 1):

For Drupal 6 try the [Menu Settings Per Content Type](http://drupal.org/project/ctm) module. It will let you select which menus to use for your nodes from the content type edit page for each content type.

This feature has been incorporated into core for Drupal 7.

Comment: this is very useful. thank you. So am experiencing that by default we have all menus and this module would help to select just needed menus. But me, I have just one menu ! others are automatically excluded.

Comment: Do your users have the correct permissions to use the other menus? Or can't you see these menus even when logged in with the main admin user account?

Comment: Am using the admin account (user 1). I saw that a webmaster installed the module "menu per role", i desactivate it. And Am always seeing that the menus are missing except the main one.

Comment: Is there any bespoke code being used in the theme or a custom module that might be altering the form output?

Comment: Not in the theme. Am going to check it modules.

Comment: Am sorry, but am bigining to suspect that it comes from theme ! Cause in php code ( menu.module) when i duplicate the filed $form['menu']['parent'] and create a second like : $form[menu][parent_XXX], this one shows all elements in menu settings tab in backend§